# get email attribute from object value - Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

is it possible to get corresponding email attribute from object property of user

```
$user = "domainname/someOU/someOU/username"
    Get-ADUser -Filter { CN -eq $user } -Properties *| Select displayname,emailaddress
```

Answer (score 1):

Email Address is store in the property `mail`. Canonical name is stored in `CanonicalName`

`-Filter *` returns all of the properties on the object. `Select-Object` is returns only the selected properties. So `-filter * | Select-Object *` would show you every property that you can return with the cmdlet, where normally the default formatting shows only a few. `-filter * | Format-List` would accomplish the same goal.

In your particular case, you only want a few properties. So not using `-filter *` and only choosing the properties you want will be more efficient.

```
Get-ADUser username -Properties mail,CanonicalName |
    Select-Object displayname,mail,CanonicalName
```

Answer (score -1):

On my company's domain, this is how I would get a user's info that you asked for:

```
$UserInfo = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*users_name*'" | select Givenname,UserPrincipalName
$UserInfo.Givenname           <-- this displays their name
$UserInfo.UserPrincipalName   <-- this displays their email address
```

If the property names are different for some reason, you can just do

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*users_name*'" | select *
```

to view all of the available properties and their values for whoever you are searching for.

Comment: Yes we can easy query this using displayname but how about the canonical name can you query that..

Comment: I have not a clue :) I would suggest including that in your original post for clarity of what you want

Comment: @CoryEtmund That was part of the original request. perhaps not in as many words.

Comment: UPN is not necessarily the same as mail address. It's convenient when it is though.